IIS site - User authentication works with http binding but not with https binding
I have a website hosted on IIS with separate bindings for HTTP and HTTPS.
When accessing the site via HTTP, users are automatically authenticated using a smart card certificate without problem.
When accessing via HTTPS, it only works in Edge, but it asks for the smart card password (unlike via http which is automatic). In Chrome, the authentication doesn't work at all; it prompts for a username and password instead of using the smart card certificate.
What could be causing this discrepancy in behavior between browsers, and how can I fix the HTTPS smart card authentication in Chrome?

Troubleshooting for TLS can be a complex task, but there are widely-used tools such as openssl and Wireshark that can assist with it. It is worth noting that web server and network administration topics are often off topic here.

@LexLi thank you! what to look for with wireshark?

Please check your site's SSL Settings in IIS, If set to "Accept" or "Require" for client certificates, make sure it's consistent with how you want browsers to behave. Edge is handling smart card certificates directly, while Chrome might not, depending on how the certificate request is presented.
